# I'm trying to show data from database in my blade.php file but I get this error "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object"

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

```
<div class="nieuws2">
        @foreach($product as $product)
            <div class="nieuwsber bericht{{$product->id}}">
                <h2>{{$product->name}}</h2>
                <img src="{{$product->image}}">
                <span>€{{$product->price}}</span>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <form class="saleform" method="post" action="sale">
        <h2>Plaats je bestelling</h2>
        @csrf
        <label for="name">Naam (voornaam + achternaam)</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br><br>
        <label for="adres">adres (straat + nr + postcode + gemeente)</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="adres" name="adres"><br><br>
        @foreach ($product as $product)
            <label for="{{$product->name}}">{{$product->name}}</label><br>
            <input type="number" id="{{$product->name}}" name="{{$product->name}}" value="0"><br><br>
            <input type="hidden" id="price" name="price" value="{{$product->price}}">
        @endforeach
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

The first @foreach works fine, it does what it needs to. But then I try and do it again in the same blade file, and for some reason it won't work. What it should do is go through each product and make it a number input, so the customer can add x-amount to his order.

My controller looks like this:

```
public function index(){
        $product = product::get();
        return view ('pages.verkoop', [
            'product' => $product
        ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the value of `$product` by having the loop name a variable `$product` (`foreach ($product as $product)`). You should use different variable names for what is being iterated and the current value of the loop for what you are trying to do:

```
foreach ($products as $product)
```

Renaming the Collection to `$products` would be a simple fix. Now you are not overwriting `$products` by having the loop set a `$product` variable.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/K69Ze demonstrating what is happening

Comment: I feel so dumb now

Answer (score -1):

OK so, apparently you can't foreach loop the same object twice in one blade file. I fixed it by changing controller to this

```
public function index(){
        $product = product::get();
        $product2 = product::get();
        return view ('pages.verkoop', [
            'product' => $product,
            'product2' => $product2,
        ]);
    }
```

and changing the blade.php to this:

```
<div class="nieuws2">
        @foreach($product as $product)
            <div class="nieuwsber bericht{{$product->id}}">
                <h2>{{$product->name}}</h2>
                <img src="{{$product->image}}">
                <span>€{{$product->price}}</span>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <form class="saleform" method="post" action="sale">
        <h2>Plaats je bestelling</h2>
        @csrf
        <label for="name">Naam (voornaam + achternaam)</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br><br>
        <label for="adres">adres (straat + nr + postcode + gemeente)</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="adres" name="adres"><br><br>
        @foreach ($product2 as $product2)
            <label for="{{$product2->name}}">{{$product2->name}}</label><br>
            <input type="number" id="{{$product2->name}}" name="{{$product2->name}}" value="0"><br><br>
            <input type="hidden" id="price" name="price" value="{{$product2->price}}">
        @endforeach
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

So that's an odd laravel thing. Anyone know why this is?